# Python Formatting Large Text

Tags: python, string-formatting

What's the best way to format a large blob of text in python? I don't mean formatting the output, but rather for readability. I've been trying to follow the [guidelines for python layout](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), but I don't see any remarks on how to format a large blob of text.

For example:

```
class GenerateCalendar(object):
def __init__(self):
    super( GenerateCalendar, self ).__init__()

def getCalendarHeader( self ):
    print """
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Atlassian Software Systems//Confluence Calendar Plugin//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
X-WR-CALNAME;VALUE=TEXT:
X-WR-CALDESC;VALUE=TEXT:
"""
```

The large block of text looks terrible and it's not indented by 4 spaces, so it's hard to read.

What'd I'd like to see is:

```
 def getCalendarHeader( self ):
    print """
    BEGIN:VCALENDAR
    PRODID:-//Atlassian Software Systems//Confluence Calendar Plugin//EN
    VERSION:2.0
    CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
    X-WR-CALNAME;VALUE=TEXT:
    X-WR-CALDESC;VALUE=TEXT:
    """
```

but this introduces white space to the beginning of the output.

Any ideas on how I can make this follow the recommended layout for python? I'd like to keep it neat and easy to read.

Is it possible to do so without doing a print for each line? e.g.

```
def getCalendarHeader( self ):
    print "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n"
    print "PRODID:-//Atlassian Software Systems//Confluence Calendar Plugin//EN\n"
    print "VERSION:2.0\n"
    print "CALSCALE:GREGORIAN\n"
    print "X-WR-CALNAME;VALUE=TEXT:\n"
    print "X-WR-CALDESC;VALUE=TEXT:\n"
```

The above is the way I'd like to have the code appear, without resorting to doing a print on each line.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The standard library has tools for this:

```
import textwrap

#...

    def getCalendarHeader(self):
        print textwrap.dedent("""\
            BEGIN:VCALENDAR
            PRODID:-//Atlassian Software Systems//Confluence Calendar Plugin//EN
            VERSION:2.0
            CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
            X-WR-CALNAME;VALUE=TEXT:
            X-WR-CALDESC;VALUE=TEXT:
            """)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjacent string literals are concatenated automatically.

```
>>> 'x' 'y'
'xy'
```

Comment: This would violate the no more than 79 characters on a line rule from the python style book.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("first line\n"
      "second line\n"
      "first part of third line"
      "rest of third line\n")
```

I do this often for very long strings.

Comment: So this is similar to doing a print on each line. I'll still need to add in a \n at the end of each line - I was hoping to avoid this by using """

Comment: *Visually* it's like print on each line, but internally, it's more like a single string. I think campos.ddc's answer is the best for what you're looking for, but requires run-time post-processing of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I typically do something like this:

```
print '\n'.join([
    'BEGIN:VCALENDAR',
    'PRODID:-//Atlassian Software Systems//Confluence Calendar Plugin//EN',
    'VERSION:2.0',
    'CALSCALE:GREGORIAN',
    'X-WR-CALNAME;VALUE=TEXT:',
    'X-WR-CALDESC;VALUE=TEXT:',
     ])
```

As it allows for (relatively) easy rearrangement and addition of new lines.

Comment: Woops, my bad on the not run, and corrected.  The extra punctuation ( the \\) is holdover from coding standards at my work, where they want us to set off a line continuation.  They're unnecessary to the actual code.

Comment: Why on earth would you use backslash line continuers when you didn't need to!  Yikes.

Comment: Just what I'm used to, though honestly I think it's just a holdover from someone higher up who thought it made it easier to read.  I'm happy either way.  Regardless, removed them now.